# Load lightbox automatically on page load

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, lightbox

I have a lightbox that loads onclick (see the link 'test' at this page: http://www.300hours.com/test.html ). I want to modify the code so that the lightbox loads automatically when a user loads the page.

My current href is:

```
<a href='/uploads/1/2/2/3/12234663/4105150_orig.png' id='#interstitial' rel='lightbox' onclick='if (!lightboxLoaded) return false'>test</a>
```

I've tried a few Javascript and Jquery solutions posted, but so far nothing works. I'm not very familiar with JS and Jquery - I think my problem must be some kind of syntax error. Anyone who can help me out with a working sample would be much appreciated.  Many thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

Just trigger the onclick event using a jquery `trigger()`.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#interstitial").trigger("click");
});
```

It's a bit dirty but it gets the job done!

Comment: Sorry for additional questions, but I must be inserting the trigger code wrongly. I've added the below in my header: `<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#interstitial").trigger("click");
});
</script>` but it still doesn't work. page here: [http://www.300hours.com/test.html]

Comment: Can I ask why you've added a `[0]` after the jQuery call to the `interstitial` element? Also a word of advice - if you want anyone to be able to review your code, make it easy to read. Your page is a complete minefield :') have you ever considered externalising your resources?

Comment: It looks like all you've added to the `document.ready()` function is an event handler, `$('#interstitial')[0].click()`. You need to add a event *trigger*, exactly as written above: `$("#interstitial").trigger("click")`

Comment: Sorry, I was trying some other suggestions, none of which worked so far. I've reverted the code back to your suggestion, but it's still not working. Am I id-ing my <a> errorneously?

Comment: Sorry for the mess - I am in the middle of tidying it up. My coding skills still needs improving though, as you can clearly see :(

Comment: I'm honestly not too sure how lightbox works, or how returning false from your conditional in the onclick triggers the event - if the code that executed that event was in a function, you're trigger would probably work - but it's likely out of my scope at this time.